# .htaccess RewriteRule api/v1/(.*)$ api/v1/api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L] not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want http://localhost/api/v1/example to redirect to http://localhost/api/v1/api.php?request=example

I have the following .htaccess but it's not working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule api/v1/(.*)$ api/v1/api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

I am using Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) PHP/5.5.14 on Mac Yosemite. I have uncommented the LoadModule for mod_rewrite and set AllowOverride to All:

```
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    MultiviewsMatch Any

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: @anubhava /Library/WebServer/Documents
same place as my php files.

Comment: yep gives me 500 error, so it's being used @anubhava

Comment: You must be using Apache 2.4, and not 2.2. `Require all granted` does not exist in 2.2, and will throw an error if used. Please confirm which version you are using.

Comment: @PranoyC: Comment out `<IfModule..` and `</IfModule` lines and retest.

Comment: @MikeRockett sorry by bad, the version is actually Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) PHP/5.5.14

Comment: @anubhava I removed those lines, same issue.

Comment: I was able to resolve my issue @anubhava you sort of pointed me in the right direction. I didn't need those if I was using a separate .htaccess file. Those are needed only if I put the rules directly in the httpd.conf file. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @PranoyC I have some issue in Rest API, if i try -> abc.com/api/rest/products?limit=2   my site return 404 page error, how can i solve this and how can i get products using rest API.

Comment: @Rathinam this question is over 3 years old now..

Comment: @PranoyC yes, i agree.. how can i solve my issue?

Comment: @PranoyC If you need new post, someone already post as a new post, can you help there https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/246597/57334

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve my issue.

1. First, I used this site to test my rewrite rules: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be
2. From there I figured out my correct rules should be:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteRule api/v1/(.*)$ /api/v1/api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
   ```
3. I also noticed that the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and `</IfModule>` are only needed if I put these rules in the httpd.conf file directly instead of a separate .htaccess file. So I deleted my htaccess file and put the following directly in the httpd.conf file at the very bottom:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteRule api/v1/(.*)$ /api/v1/api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

   </IfModule>
   ```
4. Restart apache
5. Test using curl:

   ```
   curl http://localhost/api/v1/example
   ```
6. Should redirect to http://localhost/api/v1/api.php?request=example

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all of them `[QSA,NC,L]` in your `.htaccess` file.

Simple Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api/v1/([^/]*)$ /api/v1/api.php?request=$1 [L]
```

**Update**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api/v1/(.*)$ /api/v1/api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Tried, still same. doesn't work. I am following this: http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code.

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]
```